# Filtro por fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

estoy realizando una consulta en SQL, tengo 2 campos, DIASMORA Y FEHCA quiero filtrar los últimos 12 meses de mayor a menor, los que están por debajo de los 12 meses excluirlos,
Además sacar el numero mayor de DIASMORA. mostrar la consulta solamente un registro.

este es código que estoy usando.

```
declare @fecha datetime
set @fecha = (select top 1 FECHA from tabla order by FECHA DESC)

SELECT max(DIAMORA) DIAMORA, FECHA FROM tabla
where
fechapago >= DATEADD(MONTH,12,@fecha)
group by DIAMORA,FECHA
order by FECHA desc
```

Comment: Puedes aclarar lo que esperas obtener con la instrucción `set @fecha = (select top 1 FECHA from tabla)` al no tener `Order By` vas a obtener un resultado aleatorio. También aclara el manejador de base de datos que utilizas, por el `Select Top` se puede asumir que es SQL Server pero en nuestra profesión es un error asumir cosas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tiene razón falta ordenarlo por fecha descendetente,, pero al momento de correr el codigo no filtra los 12 meses,, muestra todos los registros. Le agraderia si me puede ayudar. el motor de bases de datos sql server 2012.

Comment: Las etiquetas son precisamente para eso: para que otros sepan en dónde está uno intentando hacer las cosas. Por favor, procura añadir los detalles en la pregunta, no en los comentarios (que aquí se pierden muy fácil)

Comment: Te sugiero [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/452002/edit) tú pregunta para que completes el código de la `@fecha`, agregarle algo más de contexto y significado a los valores que intervienen (Fecha, diamora, fechapago) y ejemplos con datos donde se pueda apreciar el resultado que quieres obtener. Opino que tal como está planteada, genera dudas. ¿por qué le sumas 12 meses a la última fecha? ¿notaste que eso la coloca un año después (en el futuro tal vez)?. ¿cómo se relaciona `fechapago` con `fecha`? ¿Que quiere decir: "mostrar la consulta solamente un registro" ?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien que necesitas. Sin conocer el módelo de datos y sin contar con un conjunto mínimo de datos de prueba es dificil porder escribir la query.

Para filtrar los registros de los últimos doce meses deberías restar a la fecha actual 12 meses, y comparar la columna que tiene la fecha >= con dicha fecha.

La fecha de hoy hace un año:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()));
```

GETDATE(): retorna la fecha actual.

Quizas esta query te puede orientar para que armes la que necesitas:

- Agrupando por fecha va a devolver una fila por cada fecha distinta que haya, para los registros
  con fechapago >= fecha_actual_hace_1_año (cláusula WHERE).
- MAX(DIAMORA) retornará para cada FECHA el valor de DIAMORA mas grande.
- Está query seguramente no te va a retornar una sola fila.
- Puedes limitar la cantidad de filas haciendo `TOP 1`, pero no creo que sea lo que buscás. En este caso TOP 1 te devolvería la última FECHA (porque está ordenando por FECHA DESC) con el mayor DIAMORA para esa fecha.

```
SELECT FECHA, MAX(DIAMORA)
FROM tabla
WHERE fechapago >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY FECHA
ORDER BY FECHA DESC;
```

Esta otra query retornará el mayor valor de la columna DIAMORA para todos los registros cuya fechapago no es mayor a 1 año (retorna una sola fila):

```
SELECT MAX(DIAMORA)
FROM tabla
WHERE fechapago >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()));
```

Si en lugar de utilizar la fecha de hoy hace un año (últimos 12 meses) para filtrar quieres utilizar la fecha que esta en la variable @fecha la puedes reemplazar en la query por GETDATE(), pero en ese caso te va a devolver los registros con fechapago >= un año atrás de dicha fecha (@fecha).